# how to serve asp.net core Angular SPA over HTTP POST

Tags: angular, .net-core, lti, asp.net-spa

I am trying to develop an [LTI](https://www.imsglobal.org/specs/ltiv1p0/implementation-guide) tool using asp.net core and its Angular SPA template. A Learning Management System could use my tool (which is a web app) by embedding an i-frame of it inside their website, and they do so by using an HTTP POST request with additional form-data attached to it. If I would use an asp.net core MVC project, that POST request would reach that same action a GET request would reach and the desired view would render, but with the Angular project template I would arrive to an empty html page with this message

> Cannot POST /

I could achieve a work around by adding an action with `[Post("/")]` attribute  and redirect to the home page by using `Redirect("/")` but I was wondering if there's a better solution.

Comment: could it be that the `Cannot POST /` message is coming from express ? 
I can see `x-powered-by: Express` with `x-powered-by: ASP.NET` in the response headers... does it make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found a better way of getting the page and also preserving the form data.
I just created a custom middleware and changed the POST request to a GET request.
it preserves headers and allows setting cookies, unlike `Redirect("/")`

```
app.Use(async (context, next) => 
    {
        if (context.Request.IsAuthenticatedWithLti())
            context.Request.Method = HttpMethods.Get;
        await next.Invoke();
    });
```